# Node.js only resolving dist/index.js other files in module are not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, package.json

I have setup my project like this (using `yarn workspaces`):

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
packages/shared
    index.ts
    other.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json

web
    index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

And these are the file contents:

Root `package.json`:

```
{
"name": "monorepo",
"private": true,
"workspaces": [
    "web",
    "packages/shared"
],
"dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
}}
```

Root `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules",
    "**/.*/",
    "**/jest.config.js",
    "**/dist"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "web/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "packages/shared/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

package/shared `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "shared",
    "private": true,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc"
    }
}
```

package/shared `index.ts`:

```
export const test = (a: number, b: number) => {
  return a + b;
};
```

package/shared `other.ts`:

```
export const add = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;
```

package/shared `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Web `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "web",
    "private": true,
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "shared": "1.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "start": "node dist/index.js"
    }
}
```

Web `index.ts`:

```
import { test } from "shared";
import { add } from "shared/other";

console.log(add(1, 2));
console.log(test(1, 2));
```

Web `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../packages/shared/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Both packages compile successfully, but when I run `web/dist/index.js` I get `Error: Cannot find module 'shared/other'`. After further inspection, I discovered that in compiled JS code only `shared/index.js` is properly linked (to the `dist/` folder, see the image below). I suspect this has something to do with `main` or `types` property in `package.json`?

[image]

(`index.js` is being resolved normaly)

[image]
(this should be `shared/dist/other` not `shared/other`)

How can I make all `shared` package files to be 'visible' to `web`?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use `exports` map for subpath exports within `shared`: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports. However I don't think typescript supports that yet.

Comment: `exports: {"./shared/other": "./shared/dist/other.js" }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @morganney I found the solution. I added the following code to `shared/package.json`:

```
"exports": {
    "./other": "./dist/other.js",
    ".": "./dist/index.js"
},
```

Other solution is to export entire `other.ts` from `index.ts` (like so `export * from "./other";`), but this would result a different import: `import { test, add } from "shared";`